# CURL fails to send post data over 1024 bytes via command line

Tags: xml, linux, unix, curl, shell

I am trying to post a large XML file to a web address by using curl in a shell script.  I am posting the data using the '-F' option in curl.  Whenever I post a file larger than 1024 bytes, the file gets cut off and only sends the first 1024.  I've tried changing the "Expect:" header as suggested in another solution for PHP Curl, but it does not work.

Here is the command line I am using:

```
curl -F "xml=</fileoutput.xml" http://servername/page.html
```

As I said earlier, I've tried both
-H "Expect:"
-H "Expect: 100-continue"

Neither work.  Please help!

Comment: 1024 seems like the GET limits to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the man page the -F option does do POST so it doesn't look like it's a GET issue. The man page also says to prefix the file with an @ to use the file as the content so perhaps the command should be

```
curl -F xml=@some_file http://servername/page.html
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Even with my broken example (I fixed it and put the code tags around so it displayed properly) you got it!

Answer (score 4):

In order to poast a file you have to use the `@` in front of the URL. I think Troubadour already mentions this, but it needs to be in quotes like:

```
 curl -F "xml=@http://servername/page.xml"
```

Also notice That I changed it to `.xml` as you said you were trying to post a large XML file, not a large HTML file.

Comment: I accepted Troubadour's answer because my example did have quotes in it, but it wasn't shown because I didn't put it in a code block when asking it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the web address itself has this limitation? Have you tried posting the same file manually via a web browser?

Comment: Good thought! I just tested this out and was able to post a large >1k file to it directly via Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use -d instead of -f ?

-d seems to post the data.  As Sab pointed out GET has a very small maximum size, you must post the file and to do this you must use -d rather than -f.

[Look here.](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)